# Is it acceptable to use data attributes for layout?

Tags: css, attributes

Lately, I have been using data attributes for layout. For example:

```
<section data-ui-panels="vertical open" data-ui-accordion="stacked" class="primary new-products">
<ul data-area="nav" class="ui-list">
<li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div data-area="body" class="journals">

<div class="unit">
<p>This is my text</p>
</div>

</div>

</section>
```

Benefits

- **Code is more readable:** I can more easily spot the layout elements in both HTML and CSS. Options for the layout don't have to be verbose (e.g. stacked instead of ui-accordion-stacked).
- **Easier styling:** The layout classes might get overridden by other classes. Attributes always take priority over classes, so then don't get overridden. Many of these layout attributes work with Jquery, so Jquery doesn't get overridden by anything else.
- **Easier re-usability:** I can re-use the code between projects, without having to worry about site-specific code overriding the layout.
- **Works on older browsers** such as IE8.

Are there any drawbacks to doing this?

I found t[his article](http://intuio.at/en/blog/dont-use-data-attributes-to-find-html-elements-with-js/) that suggests there might be performance issues, but in the values it provides, the data-attributes perform quicker, so I don't quite understand it.

Comment: I can't think of any drawbacks. Any potential performance issues are going to be next to unnoticeable so I wouldn't worry about that. Modern browsers are optimized to handle complex CSS selectors.

Comment: The HTML might be more readable, but I don't think the CSS will be.
If styles overridden by specificity is a big problem for you, then you need to refactor your stylesheets. Adding attribute selectors as a means of coercing precedence is going to become problematic.
I'm not sure what easier re-usability means. Code is code.
Older browsers, meh.

I don't think there are any REAL drawbacks, but I don't think it's very helpful. I've used data-attributes for styling when it made sense (i.e. `[data-rating=4.5]` to display rating stars on a product page, utilizing the data attributes already in use.

Comment: There can be issues but it all depends on your implementation. For best practices alone, you want to develop as much of your CSS layouts with CSS rather than data attributes, aside from that you should be not store content that should be visible and accessible in data attributes, because assistive technology may not access them. Also if you're going an extra step into it and become interested in indexing via data attributes, search crawlers may not index data attribute values.

Comment: @AGE `"aside from that you should be not store content that should be visible and accessible in data attributes"`. In my example above, the screen reader wouldn't see the words "open". But it would still see all the content in the tag that contains the "open" attribute. Is that correct? `develop as much of your CSS layouts with CSS rather than data attributes`. In my example, the attributes are only being used in place of classes (e.g. `[data-ui-panels~='vertical']` instead of `.ui-panels-vertical`. Does that create any issues?

Comment: @big_smile 1. that's correct 2. it does not, what I mean to say is if you desire to create a behavior that would be done via CSS, then use CSS first. data-attributes are after all meant to support such existing behavior in CSS not to overwrite it, for that purpose you may also use CSS to overwrite CSS